# Open PayPal payment with a specific address unchangeable

Tags: php, security, paypal, payment

I get a lot of fraudulent payments with PayPal from hacked accounts, and it ends in a chargeback and I waste a lot of money and time.

I'm imagining a system where I could ask my customers for an email address, and send them an email with a button to verify that they have access to their mailbox, and if so, allow them to place an order on my site with PayPal.
The concern is that I don't know how I can create a PayPal payment button with a predefined email address, so the client can very well validate a false email address, then pay with a hacked account.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot force them to log in and approve the payment with a certain PayPal account / email address.  However, using a server-side integration, you can check their information before capturing the payment.  [Here is a skeleton demo of a server-side integration.](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server)

With that design, after the buyer approves the payment, the `fetch(` XHR to your server will be triggered, and normally this is when you would simply do a [v2/orders capture](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders_capture) request from your server to PayPal.

But per your question's requirement, before doing that you can first get info about the approver, and validate that their email corresponds to one you want to receive the payment from.  I haven't tested this scenario specifically but my understanding is a "[Show order details](http://ttps://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders_get)" call at this stage would return a `"status": "APPROVED"` , with information about the approver in the rest of the JSON body.

If the email doesn't match one you want to receive the payment from, then you would discard the order (not do any capture), and show a message to the customer that they must buy from the email you verified earlier in your checkout flow.

---

As a side note, if someone has full access to a PayPal account, they can always add a new email to that account within www.paypal.com , and check out from your site using that new email they have full control over. So I'm not sure this actually helps you in terms of security, but it does give your customers (both legitimate ones and fraudsters) an extra validation hoop to jump through to complete the checkout.